# Difference between '+' and ',' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to run a simple javascript function trying to learn the `filter` function in javascript:

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 15 },
  { id: -1 },
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 12.2 },
  { },
  { id: null },
  { id: NaN },
  { id: 'undefined' }
];

var invalidEntries = 0;

function isNumber(obj) {
 return obj !== undefined && typeof(obj) === "number" && !isNaN(obj);
}

function filterByID(item) {
 if (isNumber(item.id) && item.id !== 0){
  return true;
  } 
  invalidEntries++;
  return false;  
}

var arrByID = arr.filter(filterByID);

console.log("Filtered array: " ,arrByID);
```

The above code looks perfect, but when I change the line `console.log("Filtered array: " ,arrByID);` to `console.log("Filtered array: " +arrByID);`, it throws me a completely different output:

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 15 },
  { id: -1 },
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 12.2 },
  { },
  { id: null },
  { id: NaN },
  { id: 'undefined' }
];

var invalidEntries = 0;

function isNumber(obj) {
 return obj !== undefined && typeof(obj) === "number" && !isNaN(obj);
}

function filterByID(item) {
 if (isNumber(item.id) && item.id !== 0){
  return true;
  } 
  invalidEntries++;
  return false;  
}

var arrByID = arr.filter(filterByID);

console.log("Filtered array: " +arrByID);
```

May I know why is this happening, isn't both supposed to show the same output? I am a newbie learning javascript, please ignore if this is a stupid question.

Comment: `console.log` takes multiple arguments and logs each one. If you log an object object, chrome displays the live object for inspection. When you concat it with a string, it's cast to a string, and only a string is logged.

Comment: (The real question is why you thought `,` and `+` are the same!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do `console.log("something" + obj)`, you are essentially calling `obj.toString()` to convert the object to a string, then concatenating this string with the first one (the one on the left end of the `+`, i.e. `"something"` in my example).

However, when you do `console.log("something", obj)`, you are logging the string and the object independently. `obj` is not transformed into a string before hand. Hence, `console.log` can indeed show it differently. E.g. it may allow you to inspect the object.

How the object will appear in the log depends of `console.log`'s implementation. It may be different in different browsers or in node.js.

Answer (score 3):

`String+Array` will coerce the array to string and concatenate the two strings

The console methods allow multiple arguments (separated by `,`) and will treat each argument separately and therefore you get proper array output doing `console.log(String, Array)`.

Answer (score 0):

"+" concatenates because the fist argument,("Filtered array: ") is  a string 
and so it consider the second argument as string.

For example, console.log(1+2) returns 3, but console.log("1"+2) returns 12.